# Modeling conditionally independent observations using logistic regressions

Tags: regression, logistic

I'm interested in modeling the probability of successfully arriving at a spawning site for an individual $i$, given two impediments that are conditioned on one another.  I know whether an individual made it pass hurdle 1 ($y_{1,i}$) and hurdle 2 ($y_{2,i}$), and several other measurements that I want to use to model said probabilities with.  I'm interested on the effect of these variables on the two (assumed conditionally independent) hurdle probabilities.
$$
Pr(Y|y_{2,i}=1,y_{1,i}=1,X) = Pr(y_{2,i}=1|y_{1,i}=1,X)Pr(y_{1,i}=1|X)
$$
Is is appropriate to use two separate, independent logistic regressions to model this system (assuming that the processes describing the two hurdles are different)?